# Can I forward my customers to StackExchange websites to ask their technical questions about my software?

Tags: discussion

Similar to what Google does for their Google Apps Marketplace - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-marketplace

Comment: Keep in mind that you can't control the community voting on posts. If your customers post stuff that is considered off-topic they will have their questions shot-down.

Comment: Technical questions?  Absolutely not.  If you aren't specific about what kinds of questions they can ask, please don't send either of them here.

Comment: It might be worth to check the meta. For example [this is a small result from Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=product+support+is%3Aq).

Answer (score 7):

This is all covered in our help center article "Can I support my product on this site":

https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/product-support

Pertinent section:

> `site name` can help support your product but it can't be the only support. There are issues that only you can address, and if you send your users to `site name` for them they'll just get frustrated.

(I have used `site name` as this will be different on each site).

If you go to `/help/product-support` on any of the sites, you will see exactly what that site policies are (I have linked to the main template that can be overridden site by site basis).

Comment: That help page seems a little off in the use of "Meta Stack Exchange" instead of just plain "Stack Exchange". I'm guessing this was copied over from a template on Stack Overflow or such, with the site name replaced.

Comment: @BradLarson - kinda. It is a template for all Stack Exchange sites, with the site name being replaced appropriately.